# mongodb Date query not returning result

Tags: java, mongodb, date, mongodb-query

Hi I am relatively new to mongodb query api, I am using mongodb java driver v 3.2.

Can someone give me an example to extract the document where "prefContributors"= "RMDSContri2" and "dayString" is between a range of dates.? 
I have supplied my efforts below

```
{_id: "INSTR_ID9:RMDSContri1:2015-12-29 18:01:54.589"
 priceQuote:
 {
  instrId: "INSTR_ID9"
  dayString: "Dec 29, 2015 11:31:54 PM"
  prefContributors: "RMDSContri1"
  askPrice: 339.13794
  bidPrice: 333.13794
  midPrice: 336.13794
 }
} 
{_id: "INSTR_ID9:RMDSContri2:2015-12-29 18:01:56.589"
 priceQuote:
 {
  instrId: "INSTR_ID9"
  dayString: "Dec 29, 2015 11:31:56 PM"
  prefContributors: "RMDSContri2"
  askPrice: 374.5009
  bidPrice: 368.5009
  midPrice: 371.5009
 }
}
```

The following code with float works:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("priceQuote.prefContributors", "ReutersContri3");
query.append("priceQuote.askPrice", new BasicDBObject().append("$gte", 100.00f).append("$lte", 101.00f));
```

The date fiels are stored and retrived using "UTC" timezone.

However the following code with date does not return any result.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date start = format.parse("2015-12-29 18:00:00");
Date end = format.parse("2015-12-29 19:00:00");
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("priceQuote.prefContributors", "ReutersContri2");
query.append("priceQuote.dayString", new BasicDBObject().append("$gte", start).append("$lte", end));
```

Also tried with BasicDBObjectBuilder but still no results is being returned.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date start = format.parse("2015-12-29 18:00:00");
Date end = format.parse("2015-12-29 19:00:00"); 
BasicDBObjectBuilder builder = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("$gte", start).add("$lte", end);
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("priceQuote.prefContributors", "ReutersContri3");
query.append("priceQuote.askPrice", builder.get());
```

Comment: `dayString` field is of `String` type, would be best if you could convert that to proper Date format in your MongoDB so that you can easily execute date range queries in your app.

Comment: Your date must be stored as an ISODate() in MongoDB in order for you to do any querying on it. In the sample document you provided your date is stored as a string. There are multiple questions here with exactly the same problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That was indeed the mistake. I was using Gson for parsing the PriceQuotes, so Dates were getting stored as Strings.